# how to await when using class-transformer in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

i'm new to nestjs.

i'm trying to transform plaintext password to crypted string but i'm receiving it as "Promise {  }"

how can I await here?

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";


const hashPass = async user => {
    return await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 7);
      }
export class UserDto {

    readonly name: string;
    readonly phone: number;
    readonly username: string;
    readonly email: string;
 
    @Transform( hashPass, {toClassOnly: true})
    readonly  password: string;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible from what I can see in the library documentation. However, converting a password to a string shouldn't happen in an implicit coercion anyway, just explicitly store a `passwordHash` instead of a `password` in the dto and call your `hashPass` function explicitly when constructing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't as of now, since class-transformer doesn't support it.

The transformer decorator [expects](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/decorators/transform.decorator.ts#L10) a synchronous transform function.

As a workaround, you can try the non-promise version of bcrypt:

```js
bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 7);
```